# configuration file allenNLP

Tags: allennlp

I am trying to understand how to build configuration file for our experiements

let us take this example from the AllenNLP documentation

[training and prediction](https://guide.allennlp.org/training-and-prediction#2)

in particular this snippet
[image]

From where we got "token_embedders"?  shouldn't be "basic" as documentation [here?](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/modules/text_field_embedders/basic_text_field_embedder.py)

or do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bit of a short-cut going on here. The long form would be this:

```
"model": {
  "type": "simple_classifier",
  "embedder": {
    "type": "basic",
    "token_embedders": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

`BasicTextFieldEmbedder` is the default implementation of `TextFieldEmbedder`, and that's why you don't have to explicitly say `"type": "basic"`. `"token_embedders"` is simply a parameter of `BasicTextFieldEmbedder.__init__()`, as seen here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/modules/text_field_embedders/basic_text_field_embedder.py#L35